# Qt throwing ASSERT failure in QVector<T>::operator[]: "index out of range" in QTextBrowser

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt

I am using QTextBrowser to display string through append function.

```
    void testing::displaytext()
    {   
      qRegisterMetaType<QTextCursor>("QTextCursor");
      ui.textBrowser->append("Welcome to the world of QT");
      ui.textBrowser->append("Welcome to the world of QT");
      ui.textBrowser->append("Welcome to the world of QT");
      ui.textBrowser->append("Welcome to the world of QT");
      ui.textBrowser->append("Welcome to the world of QT");
      ui.textBrowser->append("Welcome to the world of QT");
      ui.textBrowser->append("Welcome to the world of QT");
      ui.textBrowser->append("Welcome to the world of QT");
      ui.textBrowser->append("Welcome to the world of QT");
    }
```

The above  function is being called by a thread in regular intervals, but after 
being called for sometimes it is throwing this error:

```
    ASSERT failure in QVector<T>::operator[]: "index out of range", file c:\iwmake\build_vs2010_opensource_________________padding_________________\include\qtcore\../../src/corelib/tools/qvector.h
```

How can i resolve this exception?

Comment: Is it being called by more than one thread?

Comment: I should have been more general: is it being written or read by any other thread?

Comment: yes it is being written by only one another thread other than main thread

Comment: The above mentioned function is in MainThread

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should only call member functions of `QWidget` and all its descendents from the gui thread, because the class `QWidget` and hence also all its descendents including `QTextBrowser` have hardly any multi-threading guarantees. They are not even [reentrant](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/threads-reentrancy.html) as documented [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/threads-qobject.html). However, triggering slots through signals is thread-safe and might be a solution to your problem.